# Копирование диска командой dd в linux с разделением образа на части

Tags: linux, резервное-копирование, dd

Необходимо сделать копию диска с разбивкой образа на части. Желательно с возможностью паузы. Поскольку перенос данных происходит с использованием флешки. Нашёл часть решения, но как производить разбивку на лету пока не разобрался.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdXY bs=1M conv=noerror | gzip -c > /mnt/backup/root.dd.gz
```

[см. здесь.](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/backup)

Задача скопировать файлы, но диск повреждён, несмотря на то что он монтируется и работать с файлам можно, некоторые файлы зависают при копировании. Если их пропускать, то только вручную. Единственный вариант пока это использование dd и работа с образом. Но ПК на котором он есть имеет недостаточно большой диск, а передача по сети нестабильна.

Comment: Вручную, через `dd bs=1G skip=2 count=1`

Comment: Можно завернуть в цикл: `for i in $(seq 1 5); do echo dd skip="$i" bs=2G count=1 ; echo 'Insert next volume'; read ;  done`

Comment: @Anon можно пояснение к комментариям получить?

Comment: Забить на ОС - она всё равно после копирования на свежий винт чувствовать себя будет не лучшим образом и всё равно надо будет переустанавливать. Используй `rsync --ignore-errors`. Если передача по сети нестабильна, то скорее всего проблема ещё и в матери. Просто возьми отвёртку, выкрути винт и подцепи на другой комп. Сэкономишь кучу времени. Скока инфы надо перетащить?

Comment: `bmap-tools` попробуйте. https://github.com/01org/bmap-tools